# Creating a 1-second, 1080p video with FFmpeg - Command Terminating Prematurely

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a 1-second video with a resolution of 1080p and a frame rate of 30 fps using FFmpeg. However, I'm encountering an issue where the command terminates prematurely and doesn't generate the desired output.

I've been using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1920x1080:r=30:d=1 -vf "fps=30" output.mp4
```

The expected result is a black video with a duration of 1 second, but I'm unable to obtain the output file. The command exits without any error message, leaving me unsure of what might be causing the issue.

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on how to troubleshoot this problem and successfully generate the intended video with FFmpeg.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  Running your command exactly gives me exactly what you want.  Try a newer build of FFmpeg.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.